# unable to use ScaleGestureDetector for Pinch Zoom

Tags: android

I have a class that simply displays an image. And I want to implement zoom in/out effect by pinch, so I refer to the code [here](https://medium.com/quick-code/pinch-to-zoom-with-multi-touch-gestures-in-android-d6392e4bf52d).

```
public class FullScreenImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String IMAGE = "IMAGE";
    public static Bitmap image;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen_image);

        ConstraintLayout fullscreen_background = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_background);
        fullscreen_background.setOnClickListener(v -> finish());
        ImageView fullscreen_image = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_image);

        mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                Log.d("fuck", "onScaleEnd");
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                Log.d("fuck", "onScaleBegin");
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                Log.d("fuck", "onScale");
                mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor * detector.getScaleFactor(), 10.0f));
                fullscreen_image.setScaleX(mScaleFactor);
                fullscreen_image.setScaleY(mScaleFactor);
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (image == null) Helper.LoadImage(Glide.with(this), getIntent().getStringExtra(IMAGE), fullscreen_image);
        else fullscreen_image.setImageBitmap(image);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d("fuck", "onTouchEvent");
        return mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        image = null;
    }
}
```

But my code doesn't seem to work. None of the logs is printed out. Any ideas?

I also have another question, how can I finish this activity only when not tapping on the image?

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/food_image_place_holder" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My project is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this custom image view i have created to handle pinch and drag operaions on image.
[ZoomDragImageView](https://gist.github.com/saurabhdhillon/10fa0848ef92d9c61e3dfb9cc38abb50)

Comment: @Seaky Lone did you try this?